# Create orders manually - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2

I need to be able to create orders manually from my control panel, but I can not select payment methods, how can I resolve this? This option is found in: Sales > Orders > Create New Order
In this image you can see the message I can see:

[image]

I am using Mollie for payments and it works fine, but I can not select any payment method when I want to create an order manually. 
Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you confirm payment method are enable from configuration? Store specific or website specific if you have.

Comment: Of course, the payment method is working properly and customers can buy and pay. The problem is that today I want to create an order for a customer from my control panel but I can not select payment method

Comment: Have you get the shipping method list? and have you check error log or consol log? Is there anything?

Comment: For shipping methods I created the table rate with a CSV. There are no errors in the log

Comment: I mean do you get shipping method list while creating order?

Comment: Just tried your case in a new magento 2.3.1 install and can place an order from backend with no problems, to specify a payment option you should first define the shipping method, as @DhirenVasoya says you should be presented the shipping options before being able to select a payment method

Comment: I have updated my question, because if you select the shipping method, the payment method still does not appear

Comment: Do you have payment methods that are available "offline", such as bankpayment? If you are, for example, only using Adyen of Payone for all of your payments, they may not show in the backend because the user has to log into Paypal or else, and you can't do this from the backend on behalf of your customers.

Comment: I'm just using Mollie with all its payment methods, and the different payment methods we offer through Mollie appear in the checkout, but when I create an order manually, I do not have any payment option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create orders manually, you must create a different type of payment than you have because the payment method you have is with credits cards and that is only for customers. Create a method of payment of the defaults by Magento and you can create orders manually. I hope this helps!